# How should I conditionally enable a constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, enable-if

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
template<typename Bar>
class foo
{
public:
    template<class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<Bar, int>::value>>
    foo(int x)
        : m_bar(x)
    { }

private:
    Bar m_bar;
};
```

This yields the behavior

```
foo<int> a; // no error
foo<int> b(0); // no error
foo<std::string> c; // no error
foo<std::string> d(0); // error: none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

as expected. Is there any disadvantage of this solution? What I don't like is that in either case `foo::foo(int)` exists. I know that I could use the `enable_if` in the template parameter list of `foo` itself and specialize `foo` for the two cases, but I don't want to duplicate the common code.

So, is this the best (or at least a sensible) option?

Comment: Did you mean `Bar` instead of `T` ?, or perhaps, you meant `class T = Bar, class = std::enable_if...`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes, of course. Sorry.

Comment: Currently, there's no immediate context, so it will fail to compile rather than "disable" the constructor

Comment: I don't immediately see what's to be gained here. If Bar does not have a suitable constructor for an int, foo's constructor will fail to compile anyway.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it makes the constructor SFINAE-friendly, or, let's the call fall back to another constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is there any disadvantage of this solution?*

Currently, the substitution takes place outside of an immediate context, so your approach will [cause a hard compilation error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3725aaa481e95bf) as soon as you attempt to instantiate `foo` with a type that is not constructible with an `int`.

To introduce an immediate context, you'd need a dummy parameter:

```
template <typename T = Bar
//                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~v
        , typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, int>::value>>
foo(int x)
    : m_bar(x)
{ }
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca39b659b70ee4cb)

Comment: though I'm not sure if this is your main concern

Comment: I've edited the question and added an example usage of the code in the question. "Your approach will cause a hard compilation error as soon as you attempt to instantiate `foo` with a type that is not constructible with an `int`". That seems to be wrong. The compilation error won't occur unless I try to use the constructor with `int` parameter. And that's the desired behavior, isn't it?

Comment: @0xbadf00d nope, I added demos

Comment: @0xbadf00d Visual C++ is not a reference standard-compliant C++ compiler, and this behavior is possibly a *quality of implementation* case. A compiler is allowed to reject a template for which no valid specialization can be generated

Comment: Yes, you're right and I notice that your solution solves the problem. Is there any more elegant way at the moment?

Comment: @0xbadf00d depends on what "elegancy" stands for. what is your ultimate goal? to make the constructor SFINAE-friendly? to trigger a human-readable error?

Comment: My goal would be that `foo::foo(int)` does not even exist, if `Bar` is not constructible from `int`.

Comment: @0xbadf00d then I perceive the presented solution as the best one

Comment: Why can't we simply use `template<typename = decltype(Tuple{ size_type })>` instead of `template<class T = Tuple, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, size_type>::value>>`?

Comment: @0xbadf00d because the compiler is allowed to perform substitution, since `Tuple` is already known

Comment: Please take a look at the [following analogue example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42ada49fb5fec91a). I don't understand why that example is working without a dummy parameter, but the example here not.

Comment: @0xbadf00d because you instantiate it with a class that supports those operations